# Mysql query - Identify capital letters mid string

Tags: mysql

I have a load of data i need to clear up, in particular a lot of text has joined up together some how and need to fix it.

A common theme is text that goes like this

"Hello my name is johnAnd i am here to stay"
"Hello it is a cold dayOutside today"

if i can find a query to get the second capital letter in a string i can then do a replace to add a &nbsp in there, but i cant find a way to do this in MySql

Everytime the text is joined, the word joining is Always capital letter, i basically need to find a way to identify strings with a capital letter mid word! or the second capital letter in a sentance

Any ideas if this is possible

Comment: 2nd capital letter is no good looking at the data , has to idenfify a capital letter midstring

Comment: This is going to be tough to swing in MySQL, because it doesn't support any sort of regex replacement.  You will probably have to write a function if you really need to do this in MySQL.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen. This is more of a task for a programming language equipped for text analytics than for an rdbms.

Comment: Yeah i thought so my self... :(

Comment: thanks for confirming what i thought

Answer (score 0):

You can first fetch all such text then update the row with your new text.

To fetch all such text You can use this query and update them one by one.

```
SELECT id, name FROM your_table WHERE your_field REGEXP BINARY '^[a-z,A-z].*[A-Z]'
```